# Windows Php 7.3 - Undefined type 'Grpc\ChannelCredentials'

Tags: php, windows, protocol-buffers, grpc

My PHP client is not working and will not even attempt to send a request. The only error within the code is under `Grpc\ChannelCredentials` which shows as an undefined type.

Main.php

```php
$client = new Payment\FraudCheckClient('localhost:5000', [
    'credentials' => Grpc\ChannelCredentials::createInsecure()
]);
```

composer.json

```json
{
    "name": "phpclient/phpclient",
    "description": "gRPC client",
    "require": {
        "grpc/grpc": "1.38",
        "google/protobuf": "3.17"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "GPBMetadata\\":"GPBMetadata/",
            "Proto\\": "Proto/"
        }
    }
}
```

The .dll for grpc has been installed correctly using this dll https://pecl.php.net/package/gRPC/1.43.0/windows.

I used a docker image to compile the protobuf fies.  - https://github.com/namely/docker-protoc

Comment: "which shows as an undefined type" - what does that mean? Can you share the full and exact error message?

Comment: Undefined type 'Grpc\ChannelCredentials'.intelephense(1009) and I've been following this guide https://grpc.io/docs/languages/php/quickstart/

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Is this a problem when executing the code, or solely in your IDE?

Comment: When I run the PHP code such as 'php main.php' the server is not receiving any response. I can tell in the code that after 'credentials' => Grpc\ChannelCredentials::createInsecure() the code stops running.